# yii2 form validation not working

Tags: javascript, yii, yii2

How to know if the validation has been triggered in yii2 active form?
I am using

```
$('#formId').yiiActiveForm('validate', true);
```

to validate the form, but it always returns undefined.

Comment: Why did you pass `options` as `TRUE` ?

Comment: 'true' forces the validation of the whole form... @FaouziOudouh

Answer (score 1):

Trigger the form validation try this :

```
var $form = $("#formId"), 
   data = $form.data("yiiActiveForm");
$.each(data.attributes, function() {
   this.status = 3;
});
$form.yiiActiveForm("validate");
```

I've create a function to validating active form in javascript, it will be return true/false. Maybe usefull :

```
function checkForm(form_id){
    var $form = $("#"+form_id), data = $form.data("yiiActiveForm");
    $.each(data.attributes, function() {
        this.status = 3;
    });
    $form.yiiActiveForm("validate");
    if ($form.find('.has-error').length == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

call it :

```
checkForm("formId"); // it will be return true/false and also validating the form
```

Comment: This solution not working correctly as it will most likely return the previous `.has-error` count as the check for the count of error elements gets done BEFORE the gui is even updated by the validation to add the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try

in your **MODEL**

For example,

```
 public function rules()

    {
        return [

            [['first_name', 'last_name', 'email_address','city','contact_phone', 'Address', 'date_created'], 'required'],

            ['contact_phone', 'unique'],

             ];

    }
```

first_name like input name in your view file

In your **VIEW** files

```
<div class="form-group" >

<?= Html::activeLabel($model, 'first_name', ['class'=>'control-label col-sm-3']); ?>

<div class="col-sm-6">

<?= Html::activeTextInput($model, 'first_name',['class' => ['form-control']]); ?>

<?= Html::error($model, 'first_name',['style' => 'color:red;']); ?>

</div>

</div>
```